# Celery 'Error: No nodes replied within time constraint' error - how to debug?

Tags: python, kubernetes, redis, celery

I'm having an issue that's come up multiple times before, but none of the previous answers seem to help me here.

I'm running Celery (via Docker/Kubernetes) with a Redis back-end. I'm using this command:

`celery worker --uid 33 -A finimize_django --loglevel=DEBUG -E`

(I've just set it to debug now)

I am using `celery==4.3.0` and `redis==3.2.1`.

Whenever I run `celery -A app_name status` I get:

`Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.`

What's weird is Celery seems to be working fine. I can see tasks being processed, and even if I `monitor` Redis stuff seems to be running successfully. This has also been running fine in production for months, only for this to start happening last week.

It is causing a problem because my liveness probe kills the pod because of this error message.

How can I debug the underlying issue? There is nothing in the log output that is erroring.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sadly not yet, but haven't followed it up for a while

Comment: I uninstalled celery and kombu and reinstalled and it worked. Versions: amqp-2.5.2 celery-4.4.0 kombu-4.6.7

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue or at least very similar. I've manged to fix it in my project by pinning `kombu` to version `4.6.3`. According to [this issue](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1087) on the github for celery it is an issue with `4.6.4`. Really insidious problem to debug, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As suggest here in the first answer and the issue on github downgrading kombu to version 4.6.3 itself was not enough I had to change my command a bit and use this one .. :

```
timeout 120s celery inspect ping -A run:celery -b ${REDIS_URL} -d celery@$HOSTNAME
```

Notice redis URL and the hostname.